# How do I configure webpack plug-in dependencies

Tags: webpack, plugins

I am developing webpack plug-ins. I have a scenario where a plug-in consumes a file created by another plug-in.  How do configure webpack to ensure the plug-ins are executed in the correct order?  Or how do I say plug-in B consumes the output from plug-in A?

I have registered both plug-ins in the config but I don't see how to tell webpack about the dependency.